# What is the best strategy for an Xbox 360 beginner in FPS games - Shooting at the leg followed by body or head shot?

Tags: xbox-360, first-person-shooter

I recently started playing FPS games on the Xbox 360. On the PC, I always used to go for heads. But with the 360 controller, I find it very difficult to aim for the heads. So, I give near random shots focusing on an enemy bot's leg then shots to the body or head. This is savvy, but will it help in multiplayer? Because in multiplayer, I'm all broke. Do I need to practice on it more or should I focus on heads alone? Also, please give me some tips for improving aiming.

Comment: What game? In many first person shooters, where you hit doesn't make a difference.

Comment: Games like Black Site Area 51

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It really depends on the game, but my general strategy is to aim at the chest/groin area and let the recoil turn it into a head shot if I'm using an automatic.If I'm using a burst fire or single shot weapon I aim at the upper chest/head area.

As far as general tips for aiming, try changing your look sensitivity and see what you are most comfortable with. I generally play a notch or two above default. I also play with [Kontrol Freeks](http://www.kontrolfreek.com/The-Science.asp), and now I hate playing without them.

But really there is no magic solution just play more and your aiming skill will develop.